# Download lftp file to a specific local folder

Tags: shell, sftp, lftp

I want to download a specific file to a specific folder on the server using `lftp`.
The problem is that when I download the file, it stays in the root folder.
How do I download the file to my home?

Example code:

```sh
host_File=$(lftp -e "open -u ${user},${pass}; ls; exit" $host_SFTP |
  grep "$date" | grep -oE "$host_File")
lftp -e "-u $user, $passc; get $host_File; exit" $host_SFTP
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- Change to the target folder using `cd`, before you execute `lftp`:

  ```
  cd /target/path
  lftp -e "-u $user, $passc; get $host_File; exit" $host_SFTP
  ```
- Use `lcd` within `lftp`:

  ```
  lftp -e "-u $user, $passc; lcd /target/path; get $host_File; exit" $host_SFTP
  ```
- Use `-O` switch of the `get` command to specify the target folder:

  ```
  lftp -e "-u $user, $passc; get -O /target/path $host_File; exit" $host_SFTP
  ```
- Use `-o` switch of the `get` command to specify the target file:

  ```
  lftp -e "-u $user, $passc; get $host_File -o /target/path/file; exit" $host_SFTP
  ```

See https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html

Comment: Thank you very much!!